# Working sample of WPF with PRISM 4.0 & Unity

Tags: wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I am starting on a new project in WPF with MVVM. As per the Microsoft recommendations, it is advisable to use PRISM for various reasons.

Project requirements:

1. Dynamic menu with menubar based on roles assigned to user (fetched from database)
2. Toolbar for commonly used menu items and functionalities (again role based)
3. Status bar to display general broadcast messages and other information.
4. Single middle view to load screens as menu items are clicked.

Can someone guide me to a working sample (mainly dynamic menu and multiple views loading in the main region) in this regard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're starting a new project, you might as well consider the latest version of [Prism (v6)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/). You can find the official samples for this version on [GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf), together with [extensive documentation](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Documentation/WPF) on how to use Prism with WPF. I suggest you go through these first.

As for the role based menu items, that's something too specific to find any samples on, but it basically comes down to correctly apply authorization and the necessary filtering of your menu items.

Comment: Checked a few links on the net and currently building one from scratch. Will post the answer in case some one else needs it